# Can I browse github repositories from git?

Tags: git

Is there any way I can browse git-hub repositories from git only? (Other than my own repositories)

Comment: No. From perspective of git Github is just a server with a lot of repos. The HTML UI is proprietary. But there is a Github app you may use.

Comment: Guess it depends what you mean by "browse". You can do find some information about repositories with `git ls-remote`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, git can't help you explore Github repositories.

Github is a large collection of git repositories, and git can only look at one repository at a time. So once you know the full address (URL) for any Github repository, then you can use git to clone it and use it. Without cloning from a Github repository, git can't help you in browsing Github for which repositories are there.

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences that is important to understand. The `git` is a repository, the `github` is a website which offer free git repositories. GitHub also has a paid service. You can browse the github on the website and if you clone the repository to your machine (git uses a concept of shared repositories) you could be able to navigate on it from the Explorer (on windows) of Finder (mac).

Note: If you have installed git locally, you can navigate to a directory from a command line and enter with `git init` command and you have a local git repository. You can run git without github but the opposite is not possible.